# Why is my calculation of covariance not precise

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I am trying to write a function for calculating covariance matrix. I am getting very similar answer to the built in `np.cov()` but not exactly. There seems to be a loss of accuracy and precision. Does anyone know why my covariance matrix is not as precise and accurate.

```
def cov_matrix(X):

   # initialize covariance matrix
   mat = np.zeros((X[0].size, X[0].size))

   # calculate mean of each column (this is a array)
   mu = np.mean(X, axis=0)

   # normalized data
   norm_X = X-mu

   # calculate covariance for each pair of columns in X
   for (i,j) in np.ndindex(mat.shape):
       mat[i, j] = np.dot(norm_X[:,i], norm_X[:,j])/len(X)

   return mat

# X is a 50*4 numpy array

# My function for covariance matrix
print(cov_matrix(X))

# Builtin np function for covariance matrix
print(np.cov(X.T))
```

Output:

```
Covariance matrix from cov_matrix():
array([[0.121764, 0.098292, 0.015816, 0.010336],
       [0.098292, 0.142276, 0.011448, 0.011208],
       [0.015816, 0.011448, 0.029504, 0.005584],
       [0.010336, 0.011208, 0.005584, 0.011264]])

Covariance matrix from np.cov():
array([[0.12424898, 0.10029796, 0.01613878, 0.01054694],
       [0.10029796, 0.14517959, 0.01168163, 0.01143673],
       [0.01613878, 0.01168163, 0.03010612, 0.00569796],
       [0.01054694, 0.01143673, 0.00569796, 0.01149388]])
```

Comment: Hint: are you computing the population covariance or the sample covariance?  Which is numpy computing?

Comment: @DSM Yes this is the answer. I can't believe I missed this. Numpy is computing sample covariance while I was calculating population co-variance. Thanks a lot. Please post this as answer if you want me to accept this as the answer.

Comment: For an unbiased estimator, one must divide by (len(X)-1), i guess that's what `np.cov` does. Since the difference is about 2% for 50 terms that seems to match well.

Answer (score 0):

I can observe in the result thet the numbers percision is different. When creating the covariance, each library process the data with different precisions and you will need to set it up for both to be the same. Using different precision can lead to small differences in result but not something that can impact in the result (1-2%)